# System Call in a System Call

Tags: linux, operating-system, kernel

Hi I'm trying to add a custom system call to a lubuntu kernel.I'm trying to kill a process within this system call. I tried kill() system call in original ubuntu kernel. But i got compiler errors while doing that. I have no idea how to do that properly. Thanks in advance for your answers.

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/list.h>
#include <linux/signal.h>
#include <linux/types.h>

asmlinkage long sys_my_process_terminator (pid_t pid , int flag) 
{

       struct task_struct *task;
       struct list_head *list;
    struct list_head *siblist;

    // firstly check the flag 
    struct task_struct *myprocess;
        struct task_struct *sibchild;
    myprocess = find_task_by_vpid(pid);
    struct task_struct *pp;
    pp =myprocess->parent;
    if (flag == 0){

    // this loop under this comment will kill all the children of the given process

    list_for_each(list, &myprocess->children) {
        task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);
    printk ("%s [%d] \n" , task->comm , task->pid);
    kill(task->pid,SIGKILL);
    }

    }

    else if (flag==1) {

    list_for_each(list, &pp->children) {
        task = list_entry(list, struct task_struct, sibling);

    list_for_each(siblist, &task->children) {
        sibchild = list_entry(siblist, struct task_struct, sibling);
    printk ("%s [%d] \n" , sibchild->comm , sibchild->pid);
    kill(sibchild->pid,SIGKILL);
    }
    if (task->pid !=pid){
    printk ("%s [%d] \n" , task->comm , task->pid);
    kill(task->pid,

}
```

Comment: Why do you want to add a system call to kill a process? There are already system calls like this. Show us your code and compile errors according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: However, adding a system call to the kernel is a very interesting task.  Please consider various tutorials, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884172/creating-a-system-call-in-linux

Comment: Most likely what you thought was a "system call" was indeed a glibc function wrapping the corresponding system call.  Read this document carefully as the first step: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html By "carefully" I mean "spend 30 minutes."

Answer (score 0):

You can not use the system call in a system call like that fork, kill, exit.

The kill() system call is commonly used to send to conventional process or multithreaded applications; its corresponding service routine is the sys_kill() function.

So you can use sys_kill() function on the kernel level in order to kill a process.

Usage of sys_kill() :
https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/device-drivers/API-sys-kill.html

and source book:
"Linux Kernel Development, 3rd Edition" by Robert Love (Publisher: Addison Wesley Professional, 2010)

Note : 2. Part'ı yapabildiniz mi ?? :)

Comment: Saol cevap icin 2. kismi da yaptik =)